# wrong APN settings works great

Tags: gsm, gprs, apn

This question is a duplicate of [wrong apn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182939/issue-related-to-apn-names) But none have answered. So am asking again. How come a wrong APN settings in both airtel and vodafone end up working great with no errors. I can able to connect with the internet using random names given in the APN settings. Did every network operator assign a default APN if the requested APN is wrong?

Comment: Please see my answer on the duplicate question to which you linked.  Have you tried investigating to see which APN is in the first stored context (which will probably be used every time)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue related to APN names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182939/issue-related-to-apn-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because they have already have an APN correction system.
In this case actually you dont need to put any APN in, it also will work fine.

Not all operator have this feature. So, you have to becareful if you are changing operator, it might not work.

Comment: I am not sure if the answer was updated and edited since the first comment above, but the current answer (i.e. because an APN correction system overrides the incorrect APN config) looks like a valid correct answer to me?